# how to fetch data from dropdown into spring mvc controller

Tags: javascript, spring, spring-mvc

I am working on Spring mvc and also new in this concept. I have a dropdown using unordered list and I want to get the data from the dropdown in Controller when i click the submitt button. I also have text field, which is very easy to get the test field into contoller using. but i dont know how to get the data from the drop down list. my jsp page is like this
I have implemented html code like this

```
<form role="form" method="post" action="/Web/password.html">
    <fieldset>
        <div class="form-group input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i>
            </span> 
            <input class="form-control" placeholder="User Name" name="userName" type="email" required="" autofocus="">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon">Applications</i></span>
            <div class="btn-group" id='btnn'>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                    <span data-bind="label">Select One Application</span>&nbsp;<span class="caret"></span>
                </button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" name="dropDown" role="menu" style="height:200px;overflow: auto;" >
                    <c:forEach var ="entry" items="${listOfApp }">
                        <li><a tabindex="-1" href=""><c:out value="${entry }" /></a></li>
                    </c:forEach>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>

    </fieldset>
</form>
```

and my controller is

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/password.html", method = RequestMethod.POST)

    public String submit(@RequestParam (value ="userName") String userName,
            @RequestParam ("dropDown") String dropDown) {   

        System.out.println(dropDown+" "+userName);

        return "Hi";

    }
```

I have used `<li>` as text field in controller. but on server it is showing error that it not getting the value from name 'dropdown'. If someone knows how to solve this then please help me.

Comment: does userName get populated?

Comment: yes. There is no error in userName

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring MVC will populate the model from html select, but your drop down is based on ul/li which are not html inputs.

If you can switch to select or spring tasgs form:select, form:option or form:options it will work.
You will need to use the taglib for spring tags, place it on the top of your jsp

```
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
```

If you have to keep the ul/li you need to back it with an hidden field.

To use hidden remove the name dropDown from the ul.
In javaScript attach an event listener on selection change and sync the ul/li with the hidden 
The hidden feild should have the name dropDown.

```
<input type="hidden" name="dropDown" />
```

Try the following link for hints
http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-dropdown-box-example/

Spring related documentation 
http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/view.html

Comment: If want to change from Ul/li then so many thing i have to change in     my jsp. Can you help me do it using hidden tag?